# Trigger two tables from two different databases to insert data (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

What the title says, I want to insert data from a database to another database. The first database "DB1" is the source and the second database "DB2" is the target.

The relevant tables are defined as follows:

DB1 => tbl_Target

```
==================================
Id | Date | Name | Age | Num_Aucts
==================================
```

DB2 => tbl_Source

```
======================
Name | Age | Num_Aucts
======================
```

Well, `tbl_Source` contains 40 rows of data. I need to transfer these rows into `tbl_Target`. But how you can see `tbl_Target` has two additional columns `Id`and `Date`. `Id` will set automatically. The important column is `Date`. In this column I want to set the currently date. In this case from today. How can I define this in a trigger frunction in SQL Server with T-SQL?

I have begun in this direction:

```
USE DB1
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_Insert_tblSource ON tbl_Source
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.tbl_Target ([Date], [Name], [Age], [Num_Aucts])
        SELECT ??? // How to get the current date?
```

Can anyone help me? Do I need a stored procedure?

Comment: you can use GetDate() to get current date of server

Comment: @syedmohsin But where I have to define it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I fully understood your question. But if you just want to transfer the data from one table to another, you don't need a trigger. You could achieve this with a simple `INSERT...SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.tbl_Target (
   [Date],
   [Name],
   [Age],
   [Num_Aucts]
)
SELECT GETDATE(), [Name], [Age], [Num_Aucts]
FROM yourDB.dbo.tbl_Source
```

If you want to use a trigger, write the following in the `BEGIN` block:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.tbl_Target (
   [Date],
   [Name],
   [Age],
   [Num_Aucts]
)
SELECT GETDATE(), [Name], [Age], [Num_Aucts]
FROM inserted
```

The trigger gets fired each time you insert data into `tbl_Source`. But the existing data doesn't get inserted into `tbl_Target` with your trigger.

Comment: I know but how can I define it in my case?

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it doesn't insert the data in DB2 table.

Comment: I see I have created the trigger. Well, how can I use this trigger to execute the code?

Comment: As soon as you insert data into `tbl_Source`, your trigger fires and inserts the data into `tbl_Target`. I think you should first learn about [triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) and how they are used.

Comment: Ok.. in my target table is the inserted data. But it's curious. The data is more than one time inserted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GetDate() to get current date of server

```
USE DB1
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_Insert_tblSource ON tbl_Source
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.tbl_Target (
       [Date],
       [Name],
       [Age],
       [Num_Aucts]
    )
    SELECT GETDATE(), [Name], [Age], [Num_Aucts]
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Comment: I've tried also your post, but the table in DB2 doesn't filled with the data from DB1.